# Add XML data to listbox

Tags: c#, xml, listbox

Total C# beginner here working on my first simple task list app from a windows form.

I am trying to import data from an XML file into a listbox, however I keep encountering the problem that instead of the actual data (e.g. "Pick up groceries", "Fix car", "Get better at this!") I keep getting lots of other data such as "

```
DocumentProperties xmlns="um.schemas-microsoft-come:office:office"
```

.... etc

I start off by loading the dialog box to select the file (saving as string 'file').

My code is then;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
{
  el.ToString();
  var task = el;
  listBox1.Items.Add(task);
}
```

I have tried a few different approaches and no luck reading from my test xml file. Is there something simple I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add your XML source ?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you don't specify the TagName, for your root xml document.
This is an example how to read a XML file :

My XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<head>
  <Config>
      <port>80</port>
      <thread>5</thread>
      <gSave>0</gSave>
      <bSave>0</bSave>
  </Config>
</head>
```

And the example how to read that XML:

```
 protected string[] Config()
        {
            var retStrings = new[] {"","","",""};
            var xd = new XmlDocument();
            var fs = new FileStream("data/config.xml", FileMode.Open);
            xd.Load(fs);

            var list = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Config");
            for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                retStrings[0] = xd.GetElementsByTagName("port")[i].InnerText;
                retStrings[1] = xd.GetElementsByTagName("thread")[i].InnerText;
                retStrings[2] = xd.GetElementsByTagName("gSave")[i].InnerText;
                retStrings[3] = xd.GetElementsByTagName("bSave")[i].InnerText;
            }

            fs.Close();

            return retStrings;
        }
```

If you could show me your XML file, I would give you a specific example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which has pointed out my very very stupid assumption. I created my XML file in Excel because I assumed that was how these things were done... if I do it in notepad it's fine. I think I need a 'dummies guide' book!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet..

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(@"C:\demo.xml");

   if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{ 
     for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
          {
            listBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
          }
     }
}
```